# Where do I have to put the Bump on my nodes?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

I made a material, added a bump before but it didn't worked at all.
where do I need to put the 'Bump' option on my nodes? **Which is the correct place?** I'm pretty new about using this.

Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node **Bump** in "**Vector**" category.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add > Vector > Bump. Connect like this:

[image]

You can also feed the texture directly into the *displacement* input of *Material Output* node and use Multiply Math node to adjust the strength.